# MongoDB,C#. How to create DataModelling

Tags: c#, sql, mongodb, class

I am new to MongoDB,I am trying to create with c# 3 or more comprising use cases using MongoDB. My question is,is there a better way to create classes that can store other classes since if a class have many entities it will look bad.Here is an example of what I mean:

```
    Episode Episode = new Episode() {
        Name = "Example", 
        Length = "00:00:00:00", 
        Season_number = 5, 
        Episode_number = 1,
        Series_Id = new Series
        {
            Name = "Example",
            Seasons = 5,
            Episode = 10
        }   
    };
```

And here are the classes:

```
class Episode
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public int Season_number { get; set; }
    public int Episode_number { get; set; }
    public Series Series_Id { get; set; }
}

 class Series

    {
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Seasons { get; set; }
    public int Episode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you should paste your attempt and what are the errors or problems you had Or be more specific in your question, if you have no clue  how to do that there are plenty of tutorial how to use mongo with c#

Comment: the main thing you should keep in mind when designing your classes,is that a single mongodb document in the db has a size limit of 16mb. so if there's a potential for the embedded entities inside the main entity to grow out of bound, then don't embed. use references instead. not embedding also helps with keeping the working set (db memory cache) small to keep IO load down. in your case of tv episodes however, i think it would be fine to embed them in series entity. embedding also makes your db operations fast by avoiding lookups/joins.but you'll have to learn the array query/update operations.